# BigQuery Logs - How do I know an Job is success or not

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, stackdriver

Im trying to load CSV file to BQ via cloud function. I want to know the status of this job via stackdriver logs. But Im not able to find any status-related info in the logging.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom filter like this:

```
resource.type="bigquery_resource"
protoPayload.methodName="jobservice.jobcompleted"
protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobStatus.state="DONE"
protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.eventName="load_job_completed"
```

You get only the JobCompleted, in state DONE, and only the load_job (because a query is also a job for BigQuery).

If you need to customize more your request, comment the answer, I can add more insight.